# Pasar el valor de una variable a una clase en C#

Tags: c#, variables, diseño-de-clases

Quiero utilizar el valor de una variable que se encuentra en el archivo principal Program.cs en una clase llamada Unit.cs.

En Program.cs tengo el total de unidades:

```
const int totalUnits = 3;
```

El valor de esa variable la quiero pasar a Units.cs para utilizarlo en un for.

Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Bienvenidos al juego");
      const int totalUnits = 3;
      Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un Nombre para el equipo 1: ");
      String teamNameOne = Console.ReadLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un Nombre para el equipo 2: ");
      String teamNameTwo = Console.ReadLine();
      Team teamOne = new Team(teamNameOne, totalUnits);
      Team teamTwo = new Team(teamNameTwo, totalUnits);            
      Console.ReadKey();
   }
}
```

Unit.cs:

```
class Unit
{
   private int id;
   protected int hp;
   protected int mp;
   protected bool isDefense;
   private bool isDead;

   public Unit(int idUnit)
   {
     id = idUnit;
     hp = 100;
     mp = 100;
     isDefense = false;
     isDead = false;
     Console.WriteLine(idUnit);
   }

   public void ChooseUnit()
   {
     Console.Clear();
     Console.WriteLine("Elija la Unidad: ");
     int chosenUnit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     for (int i = 0; i <= totalUnits [Acá seguiría el código])
   }
}
```

La idea es que el jugador pueda elegir la unidad dentro de ese for, agregando un switch.

Comment: Lo que voy a hacer es crear una función el la clase y luego llamarla en el program. La función llamada en el program va a recibir como parámetro la variable que necesito.

Comment: porque no pasar el valor de totalUnits en el constructor de la clase Unit?

Comment: Otra opción seria crear una clase estática de Parámetros por ejemplo y setear ahí el valor de totalUnits y luego eso podes utilizarlo en Unit

Comment: Puedes añadir un parámetro al método ChooseUnit() y pasarle la variable desde donde lo llames.